# I can't afford to pay for Statement of Purpose (SOP) proofread. What should I do?

Tags: phd, united-states, statement-of-purpose

Reliable SOP proofreading services are very costly, almost around $150-$200. I have written an SOP for my Ph.D. program in the USA, which is almost 1400 words, but I need to reduce it to 1000 words. Moreover, needs some proofreading as well. Is there any free or cheaper service (but reliable) available that can help to reduce the size and proofread my SOP? I don't want my professors to check my SOP since they don't know what the admissions committee in the USA (or other Western countries) really wants. Thank you.

Comment: When something so important is free, the value is zero. But you can try your luck with chatgpt, or fiverr.com to find a freelance with a lower rate.

Comment: "I don't want my professors to check my SOP since they don't know what the admissions committee in the USA (or other Western countries) really wants." What makes you think that the people who charge $150 for proofreading know more than your professors? If the logic is simply "they ask for money, so they must know what they are doing", this is false.

Comment: Sadly, if you are in the situation you indicate, that is, of needing someone else to ... "refine" ... ??? ... your SOP, you are already somewhat out-of-the-running. That is, if your genuine experience and qualifications are not up to expectations, making a personal statement fancier will not change anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a basic check, either free version of Grammarly or ChatGPT can be of some help. Paying for one month of premium for these is relatively affordable, so you might want to try that too.

On the other hand, you write that your supervisor does not know what US universities want. Without any judging, you can always ask in the sense that your are more interested in grammar and typos. You can also disregard the possible suggestions on removals.

The combination of the two approaches could be significant already.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other comment, that grammarly and  Chatgpt can certainly be helpful. However in my experience you would need the paid version for them to "reduce word counts" in any meaningful method that would still keep your words at heart and not lose meaning.

You could also try to do a run through again yourself. One thing that is sometimes helpful is to use the text to speech option in a word processor or similar. Then you can "hear" how it sounds. Sometimes this can be helpful to identify portions that don't make sense or don't need to be there.